# has_many :through show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to use has_many :through for the first time. I've successfully used has_many and belongs to to create cruds, but has_many :through has me floored. Every tutorial and example I've found shows how to set up the models and maybe a nested form, but no "show" views. My code is as follows:

**combi_item.rb**

```
class CombiItem < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parts
  has_many :products, through: :parts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products,
    :allow_destroy => true,
    :reject_if     => :all_blank
end
```

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parts
  has_many :combi_items, through: :parts
  has_attached_file :image,
                    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
                    validates_attachment_file_name :image, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/, /gif\Z/]

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :combi_items,
    :allow_destroy => true,
    :reject_if     => :all_blank
end
```

**part.rb**

```
class Part < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :combi_item
  belongs_to :product
end
```

**combi_items_controller.rb**

```
...      
def show
   @combi_item = CombiItem.find(params[:id])
   @products = @combi_item.products
end
...
```

**show.html.erb**

```
...
<% content_tag_for(:ul, @products.each) do |product| %>
    <li>Sku:</li>
    <li><%= @product.sku %></li>
<% end %>
...
```

This gives me an undefined method `sku' for nil:NilClass error

console output

```
Processing by CombiItemsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  CombiItem Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  `combi_items`.* FROM `combi_items` WHERE `combi_items`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `combi_items`.* FROM `combi_items` WHERE `combi_items`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering combi_items/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` INNER JOIN `parts` ON `products`.`id` = `parts`.`product_id` WHERE `parts`.`combi_item_id` = '2'
  Rendered combi_items/show.html.erb within layouts/application (5.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `sku' for nil:NilClass):
    27: 
    28:   <% content_tag_for(:ul, @products.each) do |product| %>
    29:       <li>Sku:</li>
    30:       <li><%= @product.sku %></li>
    31:   <% end %>
```

The query

```
Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` INNER JOIN `parts` ON `products`.`id` = `parts`.`product_id` WHERE `parts`.`combi_item_id` = '2'
```

returns 2 rows, both containing a `sku` value.How do I display the `product` result on this page?"

Comment: `product.sku` not `@product.sku`

Comment: That stops the error, but does not display the data. It's supposed to show the 2 selected records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is rarely any use for the `content_tag` there unless you're doing something special, and as mentioned in the comment remove the `@`. Change it to.

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <ul>      
    <li>Sku:</li>
    <li><%= product.sku %></li> 
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Removing the `@` resolved the error and after removing the `content_tag`, the `ul` and `li` tags where rendered as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`@product.sku` is nil because `@product` doesn't exists, use `product.sku` instead, without the `@`